# RectangleGeometry - Rectangle is cut

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a custom `Shape`, I started by creating a `Rectangle`.

Here's my code:

```
public class CustomRectangle : Shape
{
    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            return new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(new Point(10, 10), new Size(100, 50)));
        }
    }
}
```

When I use `100` and `50` for the `Width` and `Height` of the `Rectangle` respectively, the `Rectangle` is being drawn perfectly.

However, if I increase either the `Width` and/or the `Height` for let's say `200` and `100`, the drawn shape is not a `Rectangle` but a shape containing only two lines (looks like it it draw a `Rectangle` only it is cut - as if I have some boundaries int which the shape can be drawn).

I'm drawing the `Shape` on a `Canvas`, and here's the code for that:

```
private void MouseClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
{
        if (mouseButtonEventArgs.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            m_downClick = new Point(-1, -1);
            return;
        }

        m_downClick = mouseButtonEventArgs.GetPosition(sender as Canvas);

        var newRect = new CustomRectangle {Width = 200, Height = 100, Stroke = Brushes.Black, Location = m_downClick};
        Canvas.SetTop(newRect , m_downClick.Y);
        Canvas.SetLeft(newRect , m_downClick.X);

        (sender as Canvas).Children.Add(newRect);
}
```

What can be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DefiningGeometry` uses a hard coded location and size for the shape's geometry so the sizes passed in the `MouseClick` are ignored by the Shape when getting its geometry.

Use the Width and Height (dependency)properties  of the shape in the DefiningGeometry to size the geometry to the intended size.

Comment: Note that class Shape already has Width and Height properties. Just use them, i.e. `return new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, Width, Height));`

Comment: @Clemens - Indeed, I updated my answer. I more or less assumed that the Shape will need custom properties later on anyway